# How to stop server socket in java spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, sockets, serversocket

I am using spring boot and angular and I have a method in angular which is calling spring boot to start the server.
After the server is running, after some time which is not defined, I have to stop the server from angular by sending some request to spring boot.
How can I do it? The server is running infinite loop, it listens for client connections.
Is there a way to send some false client request and to say - hey, the client says 'stop', so stop then? Or is there something similar?

This is my controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/server")
public void startServer() throws SQLException, IOException {
    server.Server.server(); 
}
```

And this is server:

```
public static void server() throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Log.log("Server initialized on port " + PORT);
    
    listRooms = new ArrayList<>();
    Room room = new Room("Principal");
    addRoom(room);
    
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        Log.log("Established connection with " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        new Thread(new User(socket, room)).start();
    }
}
```

And this will soon be a good client, but not yet:

```
  public static void client() throws IOException {
    
    NetworkManager net;
    net = NetworkManager.getInstance();
    net.setServer("127.0.0.1", 2014);
    net.send("NICK " + "User");
    
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            net.listenServer();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Any advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setSoTimeout()` function as below to check if the client has requested to stop.

```java
//Sample code

boolean stop_received=false; //Change this to true when stop request received
ss.setSoTimeout(3000); //Set timeout to 3 seconds
while (true) {
        try{
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
        }
        catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException as e) //Timeout reached
        {
            if(stop_received==true) //Any stop request from client ?
            {
                ss.close(); //Yes. Close the server socket and exit while loop
                break;
            }
            else{
                continue; //No. Continue accepting
            }
        }
        Log.log("Established connection with " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        new Thread(new User(socket, room)).start();
    }
```

Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) for more details.